# Task when all, connection is closing

Tags: c#, async-await, sqldatareader

I'm trying to execute multiple SqlDataReaders using Task.WhenAll. But when the tasks are awaited I get

> "System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection
>   is closed".

Creation of tasks:

```
        List<Task<SqlDataReader>> _listTasksDataReader = new List<Task<SqlDataReader>>();
        _listTasksDataReader.Add(GetSqlDataReader1(10));
        _listTasksDataReader.Add(GetSqlDataReader2(10));
        SqlDataReader[] _dataReaders = await Task.WhenAll(_listTasksDataReader);
```

My "SqlDataReader" methods:

```
    public Task<SqlDataReader> GetSqlDataReader1(int recordCount)
    {
        using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            sqlCon.Open();
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", sqlCon))
            {
                command.Parameters.Clear();
                command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recordCount", recordCount));
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                return command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't the database connections be opened when the Task.WhenAll is executed or am I missing something?

Comment: You have two connections. Which connection are you getting the error on?
I would set a break point on  sqlCon.Open()  and see if your code is being run [twice] and the connections are in fact being opened.

Comment: As soon as your `ExecuteReaderAsync` call returns, your connection will be closed (as it declared inside a `using` statement). Your `ExecuteReaderAsync` call returns *before* the data has been read (it's an async reader after all!).

Comment: The connection is closed because you step out of the using block because of the return statement. You should have a look at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/22916/54013

Comment: Robert it's on the second one ("GetSqlDataReader2")

Comment: @AsusT9 you'll have to change both this method *and* the caller. The caller should provide and control the connection. You *can't* use a reader after you close the connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I'm going to leave this here, but I've just remembered that you're not allowed to combine `yield` and `await`... at least, not yet.

---

Remember that calling `command.ExecuteReaderAsync()`, even with the `return` keyword, doesn't stop execution of the method. That's the whole point of `_Async()` methods. So immediately after that function call, the code exits the `using` block. This has the effect of disposing your connection object before you ever have a chance to use it to read from your DataReader.

Try returning an `Task<IEnumerable<IDataRecord>>` instead:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IDataRecord>> GetSqlDataReader1(int recordCount)
{
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", sqlCon))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@recordCount", SqlDbType.Int).Value = recordCount;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCon.Open();               
        var rdr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
             yield return rdr;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is a "gotcha" with this pattern. Each `yield return` uses the *same object*, and therefore some weird things can happen if you aren't careful. I recommend further changing this include code that puts the data from each record in the `rdr` object into it's own (strongly-typed) object instance:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SomeObject>> GetSqlDataReader1(int recordCount)
{
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", sqlCon))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recordCount", recordCount));
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        sqlCon.Open();                
        var rdr = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
             yield return new SomeObject() {Field1 = rdr[1], Field2 = rdr[2], etc};
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to pass a CommandBehavior.CloseConnection to the ExecuteReaderAsync. Then the connection will remain open until the returned datareader object is closed: see MSDN [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204867(v=vs.110).aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.commandbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx). In that case, the SqlConnection does not need to be in a `using` statement.

Like this:

```
public Task<SqlDataReader> GetSqlDataReader1(int recordCount)
{
    var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    sqlCon.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", sqlCon))
    {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recordCount", recordCount));
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        return command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> am I missing something?

You're trying to get a `SqlDataReader` that doesn't have an underlying connection? I don't think that will work well. What happens as you read from the reader? The connection is already closed.

So, you probably just need to read the actual data before closing the connection:

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetData1(int recordCount)
{
    using (var sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("sp_GetData", sqlCon))
        {
            command.Parameters.Clear();
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@recordCount", recordCount));
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            var result = new List<T>();
            var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();
            // TODO: use `reader` to populate `result`
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```